# Formal proof that a complete graph $K_n$ is Class 1 if n is even and it is Class 2 if n is odd.

Tags: graph-theory

Recall that from Vizing's theorem, the chromatic index $\chi'(G)$  can only be either $\Delta(G)$ (we call the graph Class 1) or $\Delta(G) +1$ (Class 2). My question is regard to determining the class of a given complete graph $K_n$. I don't know how complicated this question is, so it is very appreciable if there is a suggestion for me to tackle this.

Comment: One essentially needs to find a one-factorisation in the even $n$ case, and a near one-factorisation for the odd $n$ case (which can be achieved by deleting a vertex from the even $n$ case).  I describe a proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/226717/139).