# Slicing round-robin tournament into rounds

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

I'm scheduling a sports league with *T* teams, with the following requirements:

1. Every team must play every other team (pairwise matches)
2. The are multiple rounds of play. In each round *n* * *T*/2 games are played; each team must play exactly *n* times within a round.
3. Every team must play every other team before a repeat pairing is played.

I know how to calculate the pairwise permutations of teams to produce the unique games that must be played before they repeat. What I don't know how to do is procedurally chunk those games into a round to satisfy #2.

For example, given *T*=8 there are 28 team pairs:

```
[0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4] [0,5] [0,6] [0,7]
[1,2] [1,3] [1,4] [1,5] [1,6] [1,7]
[2,3] [2,4] [2,5] [2,6] [2,7]
[3,4] [3,5] [3,6] [3,7]
[4,5] [4,6] [4,7]
[5,6] [5,7]
[6,7]
```

Let's say that *n*=3 (12 games per round, 3 games per team). If I attempt to fill the first round by adding games for each team in ascending order until I have *n* games present for a team, I get:

```
Round 1: [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [1,2] [1,3] [2,3] [4,5] [4,6] [4,7] [5,6] [5,7] [6,7]
```

So far so good. Now I continue to Round 2 using the remaining games, and I get 10 games added to the round before I'm stuck:

```
Round 2: [0,4] [0,5] [0,6] [1,4] [1,5] [1,6] [2,4] [2,5] [2,6] [3,7] ...
```

At this point teams 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 all have 3 games in the round, teams 3 and 7 have one game in the round, and the remaining unused games are:

```
[0,7]
[1,7]
[2,7]
[3,4] [3,5] [3,6]
```

I feel like this combinatorics question could be related to [Stirling numbers of the Second Kind](http://phrogz.net/svg/stirling_numbers.xhtml), but I'm not sure. How can I calculate non-overlapping partitions of the teams that have 12 members?

Comment: This may be more closely related to [block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design). One thing of note is that if doing this by hand, it's likely easier to go by round. Given $T=8$, that means four matches per round, and seven rounds, which should fit all $28$ pairings perfectly. This is, specifically, an $(8,2,1)$ design.

Comment: You are looking for a one-factorization of a complete graph, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226664/coloring-graph-problem/226717#226717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can group any standard round-robin tournament schedule with one game per team per round into groups of $n$ rounds, all you need is a standard schedule, for instance the one produced by the [circle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Circle_method): The players (in your case: teams) sit on two sides of a long table; one player remains fixed, and the remaining players rotate by one seat each round.

Comment: (For the record, this produces): $$12/38/47/56 \ , 13/24/58/67 \ , 14/26/35/78 \ , 15/28/37/46 \ , 16/23/48/57 \ , 17/25/34/68 \ , 18/27/36/45 $$